# Is there any option for temporarily disabling campaign in amazon personalize?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-personalize

According to the docs, when create campaign, even if I don't use it, Amazon will charge me for the reserved TPS. I wonder if there is any option to temporarily disable a campaign and then restart it if needed?

Answer (score 0):

A campaign can only be created, updated, or deleted. Therefore, to control costs, an unused campaign can be deleted and then recreated when/if it is needed again. Since deleting a campaign only deletes the inference endpoint, the trained model, datasets, filters, etc are left in place and do not accrue costs on their own.

Another option is to update a campaign with a `minProvisionedTPS` of `1` (lowest allowed value) to minimize the provisioned resources. However, you will still be charged for time when the campaign is idle and when actual TPS is less than 1.

The [Personalize Monitor](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-personalize-monitor) serverless solution can be used to monitor campaign utilization, auto-size over-provisioned campaigns, delete idle campaigns, and more.